# On click & during navigate, the viewCount values is still `0`

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

On click & during navigate, the viewCount values is still `0`, how can we handle the increment in this case. So that I can pass the `viewCount` to server side.

```
const [viewsCount, setViewsCount] = useState(0);

  const getClickCount = (id) =>{

    console.log("Item Clicked::"+id);
    setViewsCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
    console.log("Count::"+viewsCount);
    

    const params = {
      id: id,
      count: viewsCount
    }
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {            
          const res = await axios.put(`${appUrl}/service/updateblogviews`, {params});
          if (res.data.success) {
          } 
      } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
      }
  }
  fetchData();
  }

    <div className='blogArea'>
    {!results.length && (<div className="noSearchData"><Wave text="Sorry, we couldn't find any results..!" /></div>)}
      {results.map(({ id, date, photo, heading, blogDetails, reactCode }) => (
        <a key={id}>
          <div className='blogImageSection'
          onClick={
            () =>{
              getClickCount(id);
              navigate("blogDetails", {
                state: { id, date, photo, heading, blogDetails, reactCode }
              }) // this is how I pass the blog data with useNavigate      
            }}
          >
            <img alt="id" src={photo} className="mainblogImage"/>
            <div key={id} className='dataArea'>
              <span className='dataDate'>{date}</span>
              <span className='tags'>cypress</span>
              <h3>{heading}</h3>
              <p className="textElipsis">
      
                Sample data. The most relevant data added here.
                This to again adding most of the
                details to the react page. Successfully.
                     <code>
                        {reactCode}
                     </code>
              </p>
              <a href="_blank" className="readmoreLink">
                Read more →
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      ))}
    </div>
```

Comment: No, made bit progress, but View count getting wrong !

Answer (score 2):

React always need some seconds to update state.

So when u call your fetch, viewCount still have the old value.

There's many ways to handle this. for example:

- U can pass on params viewCount + 1 <- this in gona work unless some user doubleclicks or tripleclicks fast the button.
- U can change ur serer side "/upadeBlogViews" for a /incrementBlogViews" <- u can automatic +1 from server side without knowin the old value
- U can implement one useEffect with [viewCount] dependency to fetch. <- in this case you have the getClickHandler who increments the State. And the useEffect is gona trigger some seconds after the click, just at the moment that your State updates, then u can fetch with the value u want.

Hope it helps.

```
const handleClick(){
setNewValue(value+1)
console.log(value) // still old value

}

useEffect(()=>{
console.log(value) // new value
},[value])
```

Comment: Thank you, I was always in an assumption that useEffect() should be used during pageLoad or on loading cases. Thanks for clarifying that ! I will try let you know soon !

Comment: Sorry this is not working wit useEffect.