# Array is not iterable in useReducer()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-reducer

To practice React hooks I wrote a simple todo site with ReactTS. I faced a problem that I keep receiving an error that my todos array is not iterable, despite it is defined as `TodoProps[]` in `State` type

Error occurs logically after 'add' button click

**Error: state.todos is not iterable**

If I write `console.log(state.todos)` I receive **undefined**

I checked code on [medium](https://medium.com/@n.raj.suthar/building-a-todo-list-with-react-hooks-usereducer-95432a261c11) and it seems to be identical to mine, but anyway I cannot resolve this issue.

(Error place marked in code)

**TodoProps:**

```
export interface TodoProps {
      title: string
      id: number
      todoKey?: number
      completed: boolean
}
```

**LayoutContext.tsx:**

```
import { createContext, useState, ReactNode } from 'react'

export const TodoListContext = createContext<any>({})
export const TitleContext = createContext<any>({})

type LayoutContextProps = {
      children: ReactNode
}

export const LayoutContext = ({ children }: LayoutContextProps): JSX.Element => {
      const [title, setTitle] = useState<string>('')
      const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState<object[]>([
            {title: 'Todo 1', id: 418759},
            {title: 'Todo 2', id: 440123}
      ])

      return (
            <TitleContext.Provider value={{ title, setTitle }}>
                  <TodoListContext.Provider value={{ todoList, setTodoList }}>
                        {children}
                  </TodoListContext.Provider>
            </TitleContext.Provider>
      )
}
```

**Layout.tsx:**

```
import { Button, Todos, Input } from 'Components'
import { LayoutContext } from 'Context/LayoutContext'
import cn from 'classnames'
import styles from './Layout.module.scss'

export const Layout = (): JSX.Element => {
      return (
            <section className={cn(styles.layout)}>
                  <LayoutContext>
                        <Todos/>
                        <Input/>
                        <Button>Add</Button>
                  </LayoutContext>
            </section>
      )
}
```

**Button.tsx:**

```
import styles from './Button.module.scss'
import { ButtonHTMLAttributes, DetailedHTMLProps, ReactNode, useReducer, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { TodoListContext, TitleContext } from '../../Context/LayoutContext';
import { TodoProps } from 'Components/TodoComponent/Todo';

interface ButtonProps extends DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement> {
      children: ReactNode
}

export const Button = ({ children }: ButtonProps): JSX.Element => {
      const { todoList } = useContext(TodoListContext)
      const { title, setTitle } = useContext(TitleContext)

      type State = { todos: TodoProps[] }

      type Action = { type: 'addTodo', payload: string }

      const reducer = (state: State, action: Action) => {
            switch (action.type) {
                  case 'addTodo':
                        const newTodoCard: TodoProps = { 
                              title: action.payload,
                              id: Math.floor(Math.random() % 10),
                              completed: false
                        }

                        console.log(todoList)
                        console.log(state.todos)

                        return { 
                                     Error here
                                     \/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/
                              todos: [...state.todos, newTodoCard]
                                     /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\ 
                        }
            }
      }

      const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, todoList)

      const handleAdd = (e: any) => {
            e.preventDefault()

            dispatch({ type: 'addTodo', payload: title})
            setTitle('')
      }

      return (
            <button
                  type='submit'
                  onClick={handleAdd}
                  className={styles.button}
            >{children}</button>
      )
}
```

Don't know if I can add any more information..

Comment: Where did you wrapped your button with `LayoutContext`?

Comment: Your initial state is `todoList`, which is an array, not an object with a key of `todos`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing an array to the initial state into your reducer and accessing it as an object in your reducer so you just need to change these lines

from

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, todoList)
```

To

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { todos: todoList });
```

and you are good to go.

Comment: Could you please help with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75570226/on-click-during-navigate-the-viewcount-values-is-still-0